# IOS ASIHTTPRequest to download file and then unzip with

Tags: ios, zip, asihttprequest

Problem basics: I'm asynchronously downloading a zip file using `ASIHTTPRequest` and the `setDownloadDestinationPath` method.
Once the download is complete the `requestFinished` is called via the `ASIHTTPReqest` delegate.

That part is working correctly. I get the file and I see it on the file system.

Then I immediately try to unzip the file from the `requestFinished` callback, but the unzip fails.

If I call the method to unzip the file afterwards, via a user interface event after the fact, the unzip works perfectly.  I even tried calling the unzip method via `[self.performSelectorOnMainThread]`  but that doesn't work.

Is the file locked? Is it not really there?

Is there an easy way to say "wait a second and then do this"?
Or is that even needed?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Thats strange. Have you tried `[self performSelector:@selector(unzipAction) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0f];`

Comment: Can you also update your question with information Why unzip fails?

Comment: Debugging thru the code, I don't get a descriptive error message from the zip extract.  "Failed to open zip file."

Comment: Can you post code that unzips file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0x8badf00d got if fixed for me by using this

```
[self performSelector:@selector(unzipAction) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0f];
```